# How to install hugo-weaving gradle plugin?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

I am trying to test and work on the following library : https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

First, just to compile, I changed in Project build.gradle
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'` and update `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` from `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`.

I tried to use the command `gradle installExample` but I got the following error :

```
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:606)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:572)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:569)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:568)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:565)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:540)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/MessuKilkain/Documents/AndroidProjects/hugo/hugo-runtime/build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':hugo-runtime'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AndroidMavenPlugin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.674 secs
```